# CAPSULE EXCEPTION while deployNodes task

Tags: corda

I am trying to deploy IRS demo application on windows server, I have installed java already:

`C:\Users\Administrator>java -version
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)`

I am getting following exception for node:

`CAPSULE EXCEPTION: Could not find Java installation for requested version [Min. Java version: 1.8.0 JavaVersion: null Min. update version: {1.8=171}] (JDK required: false). You can override the used Java version with the -Dcapsule.java.home flag. (for stack trace, run with -Dcapsule.log=verbose)`

can you help with whats going wrong? In the same machine environment, I have previously developed and deployed many corDapps.

Comment: as the log says Min. update version: {1.8=171}

Comment: i updated to 181
```C:\Users\Administrator>java -version  
java version "1.8.0_181"  
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)  
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)  
``` still same problem exists, i restarted my machine after update.

Comment: do you've JDK installed? `javac -version`

Comment: yes, also i have previously developed and deployed many corDapps in the same environment.

Comment: can you check the gradle verion as well If not using `gradlew`?

Comment: I just pulled the latest corda code and tried it works fine. try with gradlew which is 4.8.1

Comment: latest corda is 3.2.X or snapsot 4?

Comment: `corda-core-4.0-snapshot.jar` it should Ideally work in 3.2 as well, checkout 3.2 release and do a `gradlew samples:irs-demo:cordapp:deployNodes` from the root dir.

Comment: it worked, I just forgot to update my environment variable after getting java 1.8.181 :).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177088/discussion-between-kamlendra-and-kid101).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by forgetting to update the Windows environment variable after installing Java 1.8.181.

Forgetting to update the Windows environment variable has also been known to cause errors of the type:

> CAPSULE EXCEPTION: Illegal char <"> at index 0: "C:\WINDOWS while
>   processing system property java.library.path: C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin;